# how to convert character within each column as sub-column without duplication

Tags: perl

I have a data.frame file like this: input:

```
    1 200 444 444
    2 310 NA  444
    3 310 NA  444
    4 NA  444 444
    5 200 444 444
    6 200 NA  444
    7 310 444 444 
    8 310 876 444
    9 310 876 444
    10 NA  876 444
```

I want to convert ecah character within each column as a sub-column and I want to put either 1 or zero in rows in the way that they represent if the the sub column was observed in that specific row or not: Output data.frame :

```
   c1.200 c1.310 c2.444 c2.876 c3.444
1   1      0      1      0      1 
2   0      1      0      0      1
3   0      1      0      0      1
4   0      0      1      0      1
5   1      0      1      0      1
6   1      0      0      0      1
7   0      1      1      0      1
8   0      1      0      1      1
9   0      1      0      1      1
10  0      0      0      1      1
```

is there any solution in PERL to do this? Meanwhile, my real data had 117000 rows and 10,000 columns and I need my output be like a csv.dataframe.and I need todo it in linux

Comment: Where is the input and what have you tried so far?

Comment: @ serenesat : I put my input in my post now. I have tried  R. I work in R. but because my data file is so huge, R does not have enough memory, so I wanna try perl. but I have no idea about that

Comment: @zara: Stack Overflow isn't a place either to get your work done for free or to learn a new language, so your question is off topic. You will find an excellent list of tutorials at [learn.perl.org](http://learn.perl.org)

Comment: You will, however, every once in a while find someone who can help. I still agree that it is off-topic though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following program will do what you want in Perl. It should work with your system Perl and does not require additional modules.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %headings;    # we will keep track of all headings ...
my @rows;        # and all new rows outside the loop

# open my $fh, '<', 'inputfilename' or die $!;
# while ( my $row = <$fh> ) {
while ( my $row = <DATA> ) {
    chomp $row;    # get rid of newline
    my @fields = split /\s+/, $row;

    my %current_row;
COL: foreach my $i ( 1, 2, 3 ) {
        next COL if $fields[$i] eq 'NA';    # skip these
        my $heading = sprintf 'c%i.%i', $i, $fields[$i];    # build heading

        # track current and all headings
        $headings{$heading} = $current_row{$heading} = 1;
    }

    push @rows, \%current_row;
}
# close $fh

# pre-sort the headings to save computation time
my @sorted_headings = sort keys %headings;

{
    # open my $fh_out, '>', 'outputfilename' or die $!;

    # Set the output field separator ($,) to tabulator,
    # and the output record separator ($\) to the input record separator ($/),
    # which holds the right line ending for the OS.
    # The { local ... } makes this only apply in the current block.
    local ( $,, $\ ) = ( "\t", $/ );

    # output an empty string and the headings
    print q{}, @sorted_headings;

    my $i = 1;
    foreach my $row (@rows) {

        # use the value for the heading in this row, or 0 if there is no entry
        print $i, map { $row->{$_} || 0 } @sorted_headings;
        # print $fh_out $i, map { $row->{$_} || 0 } @sorted_headings;
    } continue {
      $i++;
    }
}

__DATA__
1 200 444 444
2 310 NA  444
3 310 NA  444
4 NA  444 444
5 200 444 444
6 200 NA  444
7 310 444 444
8 310 876 444
9 310 876 444
10 NA  876 444
```

**Output:**

```
    c1.200  c1.310  c2.444  c2.876  c3.444
1   1   0   1   0   1
2   0   1   0   0   1
3   0   1   0   0   1
4   0   0   1   0   1
5   1   0   1   0   1
6   1   0   0   0   1
7   0   1   1   0   1
8   0   1   0   1   1
9   0   1   0   1   1
10  0   0   0   1   1
```

I've built it with the example data in a `__DATA__` section at the end of the program, but the code for using a file as the data source is there, you just need to uncomment them.

With the number of rows and cols you have, this will still eat some memory, but it does not create the full file in memory. It collects all the possible headings in a hash, but only saves the `1`s for each rows per heading as there is no need to save the `0`s.

This is what the data structure looks like for the example.

```
[
    [0] {
        c1.200   1,
        c2.444   1,
        c3.444   1
    },
    [1] {
        c1.310   1,
        c3.444   1
    },
    [2] {
        c1.310   1,
        c3.444   1
    },
    [3] {
        c2.444   1,
        c3.444   1
    },
    [4] {
        c1.200   1,
        c2.444   1,
        c3.444   1
    },
    [5] {
        c1.200   1,
        c3.444   1
    },
    [6] {
        c1.310   1,
        c2.444   1,
        c3.444   1
    },
    [7] {
        c1.310   1,
        c2.876   1,
        c3.444   1
    },
    [8] {
        c1.310   1,
        c2.876   1,
        c3.444   1
    },
    [9] {
        c2.876   1,
        c3.444   1
    }
]
```

Comment: I tried to run this program. bu I got this error:

Comment: @zara what error? You didn't post an error.

Comment: I tried to run this program. but I got this error: skarimi@signal[09:18][~]$ chmod +x per.pl
skarimi@signal[09:18][~]$ ./per.pl > boo.txt &
[1] 4383
skarimi@signal[09:19][~]$ ./per.pl: line 1: my: command not found
./per.pl: line 2: my: command not found
Couldn't get a file descriptor referring to the console
./per.pl: line 5: syntax error near unexpected token `)'
./per.pl: line 5: ` while ( my $row = <$fh> ) {'
why is that please?

Comment: @zara You didn't put a shebang in the first line of the program, but gave it execution permissions and tried running it with `./foo.pl`. Now the shell doesn't know what to run it with. Just run `perl foo.pl` :)

Comment: but the control file name is per.pl and not foo.pl

Comment: @ simbabque: this is my control file inside, my input file name is boo.txt:

Comment: @ simbabque:my %headings;    # we will keep track of all headings ...                       
my @rows;        # and all new rows outside the loop                            

 open my $fh, '<', 'boo.txt' or die $!;
 while ( my $row = <$fh> ) {
#while ( my $row = <DATA> ) {                                                   
    chomp $row;    # get rid of newline                                         
    my @fields = split /\s+/, $row;

could you please have look to this ? did I change it correctly?

Comment: @zara that looks correct, from what I can tell without newlines. Does it work?

Comment: no it does not. but I uncomment the the code for using my file and comment on the othe one. it does not work

Comment: @ simbabque: this is the first error: ./per.pl: line 1: my: command not found

Comment: @zara I told you to run it using the perl interpreter. If you do not add a shebang line **it will not work** the way you run the script.

Comment: @ simbabque : Hello again. I hope I can ask another question about this program you have written long time go. May I ?

Comment: @zara if it's a real new question, please create a new question. If it's just a comment, go ahead.